# EF Core 2.2 AsNoTracking + Include Throws a Lazyloading error. How to fix?

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.2

I have something like this

```
var result = dbContext.CompanyProducts.Include(x => x.Product).AsNotracking().Where(//some condtions).GroupBy(x => x.id).ToList()

var p = result.First().Product
```

but I get

```
"Error generated for warning 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DetachedLazyLoadingWarning: 

An attempt was made to lazy-load navigation property 'Product' on detached entity of type 'CompanyProductProxy'. 

    Lazy-loading is not supported for detached entities or entities that are loaded with 'AsNoTracking()'.'. 
    This exception can be suppressed or logged by passing event ID 'CoreEventId.DetachedLazyLoadingWarning' to the 'ConfigureWarnings'
     method in 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' or 'AddDbContext'."}
```

Why does it think it is lazy loading when I used include?

Answer (score 2):

Lazy loading won't work when using `AsNoTracking` method.

You have two options:

1. Remove `AsNoTracking`
2. Ignore the warning and simply get null for your relationships

You can configure EF to ignore this error:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder
        .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
        .ConfigureWarnings(warnings => warnings.Ignore(CoreEventId.DetachedLazyLoadingWarning));
}
```

Comment: I know lazy loading won't work with Notracking but that's why I am using Include, what my understanding is it will eager load the data so that data should be there.

Comment: @chobo2 So, simply ignore it using `ConfigureWarnings`.

Comment: ok but still does not solve the problem that the Product object has not been loaded now I just see a null for the product.

Comment: @chobo2 Include it after `AsNoTracking`.

Comment: I tried it every way. dbContext.CompanyProducts.AsNoTracking().Include(x => x.Product) and dbContext.CompanyProducts.Include(x => x.Product).AsNoTracking() still gives me null

Comment: It seems it's a historical bug from [ef core 2.1](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/13173) that it's not solved and is still on the backlog milestone.

Comment: That's a bummer, ok guess back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn off lazy loading, either at the project level in **Startup.cs** or for a specific action only, like so:

```
var result = dbContext.CompanyProducts.Include(x => x.Product).AsNotracking().ToList();
dbContext.ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

var p = result.First().Product;
```

Once `LazyLoadingEnabled` is set to false, you can then check `Product` for null as you would expect.